# Error - android has no zero argument constructor - listView

Tags: android, listview, constructor

In my Main Activity, there are buttons. When it is clicked it opens a listview in a different activity(i.e. ListView). When I try to click on the button, the app crashes and shows the above error. I am completely clueless about how to solve it. Kindly help me.

In the main activity code, the button listener is -

```
            b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                I = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ListView.class);
                startActivity(I);
            }
        });
```

Then in another activity named as - ListView, the code is -

```
public class ListView extends AppCompatActivity {
android.widget.ListView lv;
BroadReceive br;
IntentFilter IF;
Intent I;
Button b;
LoginActivity la;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
    lv = (android.widget.ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    b = (Button) la.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    IF = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(br.PutListOfWiFi(lv), IF);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String item;
            I = new Intent(ListView.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(I);
            item = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            b.setText(item);
        }

    });
}
```

}

Kindly help me!!

ErrorLog (LogCat) The name of the main activity is (LoginActivity) -

10-14 14:44:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(7404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectwifi/com.example.projectwifi.ListViewNames}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.example.projectwifi.LoginActivity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

I have removed the constructor, now its a different error. Kindly comment. I am new to this language. Please help.

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: `ListView` is already a class defined in the android libraries (as you may be aware, since you are importing it). You are attempting to redefine the class in your code. If you simply want to make a custom `ListView`, I recommend making a `CustomListView` class that extends `ListView`.

Comment: @nukeforum - I have tried this option but it gives the same error. The name i chose was ListViewNames.

Comment: @ArpitKumar Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest my comment would fix the error you're experiencing. It won't. I suggest reading Blackbelt's answer below, his is correct.

Comment: @nukeforum This is a discussion forum and I appreciate any comment which intends to find the answer. Hence no offence taken. I rally appreciate your efforts.:)

Comment: Down voters care to explain so we can all learn?

Answer (score 3):

You can't overload the constructor of a class that extends `Activity`. Get rid of

`public ListView(Button button) {`

its existence is pointless. You can't use the `new` operator on a class that extends `Activity`

Comment: When the item is selected from the list view, it should set text on the button which exists in the main activity. How should I do that if I will remove the constructor?

Comment: which one is the MainActivity?

Comment: The MainActivity (named as LoginActivity) contains the button onclicklistener. When the button is clicked a listview should open in another activity (named as ListView).

Comment: @ArpitKumar Why do you need the reference to the Button you're passing in? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When the user clicks an item in the list view, it should display the selected item on that button by using settext. Why I am using like this not the spinner? Well this is because, I want a default value to be there whenever user sees the app for the first time.

Comment: I just mean, why do you need to pass in a button like that? Why not just use `findViewById(R.id.your_button_id)`?

Comment: Yes, now I am trying that only.

Comment: It didnt work, now the log cat is showing a different error. Please have a look. I have mentioned in the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove your constructor and when you need your button to setOnClickListener use view.findViewById(int) to find it.

P/s You have to strictly follow the guide on developer.android.com. You should not treat you app like in Standard Java App because the Android Framework have done many things (components) for the apps.

## UPDATE

you are in the ListView class which is an Activity, then when you call findViewById(int) on that activity, it will find the view if that activity which is set by calling setContentView(int) before.

In your case, make sure that your android.widget.ListView is present in your R.layout.something that you set on setContentView().

If you call view.findViewById() on a view, then it will find only on that view and its children.

Comment: I think I am getting your point. SO in ListView Activity if I can create the MainActivity object and from that I call the button via findviewbyId it will work. Am i getting it the right way?

Comment: The way you have mentioned, I have done exactly in the same manner. But whatever the user selects from the list view, it should show on the button in the MainActivity (the name is LoginActivity). The app crashes when I try to refer the button of the mainactivity in the ListView activity.

Comment: If you want to pass information between activity, use intent.setExtra(). Don't use this, you should not instantiate the activity your self which is the system's job.